# rsync exclude pattern for `/index.php` but not for `/dir/subdir/index.php`

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am rsyncing files from `localhost` to `host1` using the following command.

```
rsync     -vq -ar \
          --exclude="index.php" \
          --exclude="var*" \
          --exclude=".svn*" \
          --exclude="*~" \
          --exclude="Doxyfile" \
          --exclude="*.kdev*" 
          --exclude="nbproject" \
          ${SRC} root@${HOST}:${RLOC} && echo Files synchronised.
```

The problem with this command is it excludes `index.php` from any directory. But I want to exclude it only from root. That is I want  `${SRC}/index.php` should not be copied. But other will. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `--exclude=/index.php` or `--exclude="$SRC/index.php"`?

Comment: @NiklasB How blind I am! The second pattern makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All rsync exclude paths use relative position to the source directory.  So if you do --exclude="/index.php" it works how you want.  But make sure ${SRC} has a trailing slash.

Comment: Why put trailing `/` after `${SRC}` ?

Comment: Because otherwise it won't detect the /index.php as relative to the source path.  Not sure why rsync is made that way, but I found that to be the case